# Cannot reach deployed app from other PC in the same network

Tags: c#, iis, networking, dns

I have very simple app written in C#. I hosting it on IIS (my local PC with Windows 10).
There is my configuration on IIS (ADVANCED):
[image]

And my deploy profile from VisualStudio:
[image]

My hosts.txt:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       local-app
    127.0.0.1       http://local-app:8082/
```

I can browse my deployed app from my local PC, but i cannot browse it from another PC or mobile (connected via Wi-Fi in the same network).

What do I need to change to have access from other devices?
Regards

Comment: What URL are you using to try to access it from another computer? It looks like it may work using the IP of the computer hosting the site: http://[IP of the computer]:8082

Comment: You merely set up this machine for local traffic, so no doubt remote traffic won't work. Get started from https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background and you also need to open the port on Windows Firewall.

Comment: @LexLi Sorry, but this link explains nothing. Moreover i don't use jexus.

Comment: That article warns you that setting a certain site binding has implication on what kind of HTTP your site can take. Clearly in your current situation, no other device (PC or mobile) can generate a proper HTTP request, so "cannot browser it" is expected. Usually you need a DNS server for your local network (or hack every other devices) to resolve `local-app` to this IIS machine. That's not programming related any more but purely a networking question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the application through other devices, first you need to connect another computer or mobile device to the same LAN, and close the firewall or open the port bound to the website on the PC where IIS is located, and then you can type the IP+port in the browser to visit your site.

Below is the command to [add a firewall rule to enable the port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/netsh-advfirewall-firewall-control-firewall-behavior):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 80" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
```

You can try to use the ping command on other devices to interact with the device where IIS is located. If the interaction is successful, it means you can access.